# Running Model within ArcMap using VBA?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3, vba

I would like to Run/execute a model within ArcMap 9.3.1 vba. I can run it in vba by exporting out the VBS script and importing it into vba, however I'm wondering if there is an easier way to just call the model by where it is located instead of using the VBS script (e.g. see below).

Run "C:\Data\New File Geodatabase.gdb\Toolbox\Model"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will run existing tools or models that your create:

```
Private Sub opentool_Click()
'Ensure that there are references set to the
'ESRI GeoprocessingUI Object Library and the
'ESRI Geoprocessing Object Library.
'Go to Tools > References to do this

Dim pUID As New UID
pUID = "esriGeoprocessingUI.ArcToolboxExtension"

Dim pATBExt As IArcToolboxExtension
Set pATBExt = Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pUID)

Dim pAtb As IArcToolbox
Set pAtb = pATBExt.ArcToolbox

Dim pTool As IGPTool

'* Use this line for custom tools or models
'* ========================================
Set pTool = pAtb.GetToolbyNameString("Model8")

'* Use this line for existing tools
'* ================================
'Set pTool = pAtb.GetToolbyNameString("buffer_analysis")

Dim pCommand As IGPToolCommandHelper
Set pCommand = New GPToolCommandHelper
pCommand.SetTool pTool
pCommand.Invoke Nothing

End Sub
```

Right click on your tool in ArcToolox and go to properties to find the model name.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So the model dialog opens, I click OK to run and I get this error.

Comment: WARNING 000728: Field GeoPhyLogs does not exist within table

Comment: ERROR 000735: Input Table: Value is required, ERROR 0007: Input Dataset: Value is required, ERROR 000735: Join Table: Value is required, ERROR 000735 Input Table is required, WARNING 000728: Field BUFF_DIST does not exist within table, The value does not exist.

Comment: However, the model does run fine when I open the model via edit and run it.

Comment: I forgot to add some references to my project, your code works fine.  Is there a way to automate a "Enter" keystroke or to click the "Ok" button when the model dialog opens?